# Is Visual Studio 2015 Webview Same as Edge?

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015

Meaning, if whatever html/css/javascript I show on Windows 10 Edge am I guaranteed it will work the same on the visual studio webview?

Comment: that thing is actually used?

Comment: yeah, there's this little thing called cordova..

Comment: yes it will............

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which Windows platform you are targeting with Cordova. If you target Windows 8/8.1, it will use the Internet Explorer engine. If you target Windows 10 (IE a Universal Windows App), it will use Edge. This would be the same engine for both phone and desktop.

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: I worked on Cordova support in Visual Studio in 2014)

This is not *absolutely* guaranteed.

For a start, Cordova applications running on Android or iOS are going to be using Blink and WebKit respectively, and on Windows Phone they would be running a slightly different version of the Edge/Trident engine than whatever is running on your desktop system (while they are meant to have a minimum web feature set, builds of Edge/Trident for Windows Phone and Desktop Windows are taken from different snapshot dates from the source code, so there might be slight differences.

Comment: but let's say I'm running a cordova app on the desktop, is it the same as edge in that case?